# Callback for new Fingerprint add, delete or update in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I am providing authentication via fingerprint which is working fine.
Now If user add,update or delete fingerprint in device I need some callback or some event through which i can disable the feature which is a requirement.

Logic:
1) If i am able to get total number of fingerprints available with ids.
2) Receiver for any changes in fingerprint manager.

Please help!!

Comment: There is [FingerPrintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html) and there is a method called [hasEnrolledFingerprints](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#hasEnrolledFingerprints) so i guess based on the boolean value you can enable or disable this feature!!!

Comment: @Kostas Drakonakis that can verify only finger prints are available or not but what i want is callback for add,update or delete fingerprint.

Comment: Any solution for this? Even i am stuck on the same.

Comment: @Swapnil did you get any solution?

Comment: @Swapnil did you get any solution, please share it with us. I am also looking a solution.